# IntelliJ does not include libraries with missing classes on the classpath?

Tags: java, maven, ant, jar, intellij-idea

When I set up a run configuration in IntelliJ for my 'Installation' module, I use my 'Installation' module's classpath. My 'Installation' module has dependencies on two jars from the 'Engine' module and 'Game' module. I have the run configuration set up to, before launch, build the artifacts (the jars that the 'Installation' module depends on). The only issue is that it appears to build the classpath first, see that the jars are missing, and then it removes the jars from the classpath, before creating them in the next step, resulting in the jars being present in the 'Installation' module, but not being linked to by the classpath. If the application is run a second time, it works, because the jars are now present when it creates the classpath.

Is there any way to force IntelliJ to include all libraries/jars, even if they are not present, on the classpath?

I could add the libraries/jars as module dependencies instead, and this works, but it isn't quite 'right' as the 'Installation' module doesn't depend on the other modules, it just depends on the correctly-named jars being there.

Comment: Using module dependencies is the 'normal' way to do this in IntelliJ.  When you configure Before Launch tasks, they are, as the name suggests, run before launch and so I don't understand why the JARs aren't present when the Installation module is run.  Are the JARs missing from the classpath in the console window when the Installation module is run?

Comment: Yes, the jars are missing from the -classpath parameter the first time it is run, but not the second time, leading me to believe that the values for '-classpath' are determined before the 'before launch' operations are run, and that it is excluding missing libraries.